# Database tables from entities are not created

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, netbeans, glassfish

I made a new maven web application in netbeans. I wrote a couple of entity classes like this one:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

public enum Role { ADMIN,USER;}

@Version
private int version;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
private String username;

private String password;
private String fullName;
private Role role;

@ManyToMany
private List<Project> projects;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "employee")
private List<Task> tasks;

@ManyToMany
private List<Meeting> meetings;

public void setRoleFromString(String stringRole){
    role = Role.valueOf(stringRole);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Employee other = (Employee) obj;
    if (fullName == null) {
        if (other.fullName != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!fullName.equals(other.fullName))
        return false;
    if (id != other.id)
        return false;
    if (password == null) {
        if (other.password != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!password.equals(other.password))
        return false;
    if (role != other.role)
        return false;
    if (username == null) {
        if (other.username != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!username.equals(other.username))
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((fullName == null) ? 0 : fullName.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
    result = prime * result + ((password == null) ? 0 : password.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((role == null) ? 0 : role.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((username == null) ? 0 : username.hashCode());
    return result;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}

public void setFullName(String fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
}

public Role getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(Role role) {
    this.role = role;
}

public List<Project> getProjects() {
    return projects;
}

public void setProjects(List<Project> projects) {
    this.projects = projects;
}

public List<Task> getTasks() {
    return tasks;
}

public void setTasks(List<Task> tasks) {
    this.tasks = tasks;
}

public List<Meeting> getMeetings() {
    return meetings;
}

public void setMeetings(List<Meeting> meetings) {
    this.meetings = meetings;
}
}
```

When I deploy my application on the GlassFish server, the application doesn't create any tables for my entities. I had some problems with maven and the Oracle jdbc driver, because of some licensing issues between them, but I have the nessecary JARs in my app.

How can I fix this?

I post the persistence.xml as well for reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="ProjectManagerWeb" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create-or-extend-tables"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="aleks"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="12345"/>
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**sever.log**

```
[2015-10-25T01:20:45.352+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-LOGGING-00009] [javax.enterprise.logging] [tid: _ThreadID=15 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244563] [timeMillis: 1445725245352] [levelValue: 800] [[
Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (build 13)]]

[2015-10-25T01:20:45.359+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-LOGGING-00010] [javax.enterprise.logging] [tid: _ThreadID=15 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244563] [timeMillis: 1445725245359] [levelValue: 800] [[
Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter]]

[2015-10-25T01:20:45.711+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01115]  [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=16  _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244582] [timeMillis: 1445725245711]  [levelValue: 800] [[
Realm [admin-realm] of classtype   [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.]]

[2015-10-25T01:20:45.731+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01115]   [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244582] [timeMillis: 1445725245731] [levelValue: 800] [[
Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.]]

[2015-10-25T01:20:45.755+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01115] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244582] [timeMillis: 1445725245755] [levelValue: 800] [[
Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.]]

[2015-10-25T01:20:46.397+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [SEC-SVCS-00100] [javax.enterprise.security.services] [tid: _ThreadID=15 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244563] [timeMillis: 1445725246397] [levelValue: 800] [[
 Authorization Service has successfully initialized.]]

[2015-10-25T01:20:46.426+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.ha.store.spi.BackingStoreFactoryRegistry] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244583] [timeMillis: 1445725246426] [levelValue: 800] [[
Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry]]

[2015-10-25T01:20:46.989+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00043] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=14 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244560] [timeMillis: 1445725246989] [levelValue: 1000] [[
Application previously deployed is not at its original location any more: file:/C:/Users/Aleksandar/Desktop/WebProjectManager/target/WebProjectManager-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/]]

[2015-10-25T01:20:48.112+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244582] [timeMillis: 1445725248112] [levelValue: 800] [[
Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 650ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]]]

[2015-10-25T01:20:48.251+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244582] [timeMillis: 1445725248251] [levelValue: 800] [[
Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 5ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]]]

[2015-10-25T01:20:48.375+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244582] [timeMillis: 1445725248375] [levelValue: 800] [[
Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 81ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]]]

[2015-10-25T01:20:48.567+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244583] [timeMillis: 1445725248567] [levelValue: 800] [[
Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 3ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]]]

[2015-10-25T01:20:49.415+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=14 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244560] [timeMillis: 1445725249415] [levelValue: 800] [[
visiting unvisited references]]

[2015-10-25T01:20:51.662+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01002] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=14 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244560] [timeMillis: 1445725251662] [levelValue: 800] [[
Java security manager is disabled.]]

[2015-10-25T01:20:51.663+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01010] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=14 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244560] [timeMillis: 1445725251663] [levelValue: 800] [[
 Entering Security Startup Service.]]

[2015-10-25T01:20:51.676+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01143] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=14 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244560] [timeMillis: 1445725251676] [levelValue: 800] [[
 Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.]]

 [2015-10-25T01:20:51.801+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01011] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=14 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244560] [timeMillis: 1445725251801] [levelValue: 800] [[
 Security Service(s) started successfully.]]

[2015-10-25T01:20:52.707+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00198] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=14 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244560] [timeMillis: 1445725252707] [levelValue: 800] [[
Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080]]

[2015-10-25T01:20:52.740+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00198] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=14 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244560] [timeMillis: 1445725252740] [levelValue: 800] [[
 Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181]]

 [2015-10-25T01:20:52.748+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00198] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=14 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244560] [timeMillis: 1445725252748] [levelValue: 800] [[
 Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848]]

[2015-10-25T01:20:52.861+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00200] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=14 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244560] [timeMillis: 1445725252861] [levelValue: 800] [[
 Created virtual server server]]

[2015-10-25T01:20:52.867+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00200] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=14 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244560] [timeMillis: 1445725252867] [levelValue: 800] [[
Created virtual server __asadmin]]

[2015-10-25T01:20:53.588+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-CORE-00306] [javax.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=14 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244560] [timeMillis: 1445725253588] [levelValue: 800] [[
Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web]]

[2015-10-25T01:20:53.590+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00201] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=14 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244560] [timeMillis: 1445725253590] [levelValue: 800] [[
Virtual server server loaded default web module ]]

[2015-10-25T01:20:55.788+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=14 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244560] [timeMillis: 1445725255788] [levelValue: 800] [[
 visiting unvisited references]]

 [2015-10-25T01:20:55.918+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=14 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244560] [timeMillis: 1445725255918] [levelValue: 800] [[
 visiting unvisited references]]

 [2015-10-25T01:20:55.924+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=14 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244560] [timeMillis: 1445725255924] [levelValue: 800] [[
 visiting unvisited references]]

[2015-10-25T01:20:55.928+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=14 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244560] [timeMillis: 1445725255928] [levelValue: 800] [[
visiting unvisited references]]

[2015-10-25T01:20:57.299+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] []   [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=14 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244560] [timeMillis: 1445725257299]  [levelValue: 900] [[
The web application [unknown] registered the JDBC driver [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.]]

[2015-10-25T01:21:01.234+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [jsf.config.listener.version] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] [tid: _ThreadID=14 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244560] [timeMillis: 1445725261234] [levelValue: 800] [[
Initializing Mojarra 2.2.7 ( 20140610-1547 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.7@13362) for context '/ProjectManagerWeb']]

[2015-10-25T01:21:04.255+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] [tid: _ThreadID=14 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244560] [timeMillis: 1445725264255] [levelValue: 800] [[
 HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final]]

[2015-10-25T01:21:06.388+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] [tid: _ThreadID=14 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244560] [timeMillis: 1445725266388] [levelValue: 800] [[
 Running on PrimeFaces 5.0]]

[2015-10-25T01:21:06.406+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00172] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=14 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244560] [timeMillis: 1445725266406] [levelValue: 800] [[
Loading application [ProjectManagerWeb] at [/ProjectManagerWeb]]]

[2015-10-25T01:21:06.434+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00022] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=14 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244560] [timeMillis: 1445725266434] [levelValue: 800] [[
Loading application ProjectManagerWeb done in 19 444 ms]]

[2015-10-25T01:21:06.439+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00017] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1445725266439] [levelValue: 800] [[
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (13) startup time : Felix (26 644ms), startup services(21 890ms), total(48 534ms)]]

[2015-10-25T01:21:06.775+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=14 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1445725244560] [timeMillis: 1445725266775] [levelValue: 800] [[
Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 4ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]]]

[2015-10-25T01:21:07.160+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-BOOTSTRAP-00027]  [javax.enterprise.bootstrap] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1445725267160] [levelValue: 800] [[
Registered  com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@10ee03a as  OSGi service registration:  org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@1f94401.]]

[2015-10-25T01:21:08.189+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00198] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=88 _ThreadName=pool-20-thread-1] [timeMillis: 1445725268189] [levelValue: 800] [[
Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181]]

[2015-10-25T01:21:08.307+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-JMX-00005] [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=64 _ThreadName=Thread-16] [timeMillis: 1445725268307] [levelValue: 800] [[
 JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://213.191.173.213:8686/jndi/rmi://213.191.173.213:8686/jmxrmi]]

[2015-10-25T01:21:08.375+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=88 _ThreadName=pool-20-thread-1] [timeMillis: 1445725268375] [levelValue: 800] [[
Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 62ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]]]

[2015-10-25T01:21:08.775+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00198] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=85 _ThreadName=pool-19-thread-1]  [timeMillis: 1445725268775] [levelValue: 800] [[
 Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080]]

 [2015-10-25T01:21:08.788+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=85 _ThreadName=pool-19-thread-1] [timeMillis: 1445725268788] [levelValue: 800] [[
 Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 4ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]]]

[2015-10-25T01:21:10.976+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1445725270976] [levelValue: 800] [[
visiting unvisited references]]

[2015-10-25T01:21:11.582+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1445725271582] [levelValue: 800] [[
 visiting unvisited references]]

[2015-10-25T01:21:11.613+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1445725271613] [levelValue: 800] [[
 visiting unvisited references]]

 [2015-10-25T01:21:11.619+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1445725271619] [levelValue: 800] [[
 visiting unvisited references]]

 [2015-10-25T01:21:11.622+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1445725271622] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

  [2015-10-25T01:21:14.544+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [jsf.config.listener.version] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1445725274544] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Initializing Mojarra 2.2.7 ( 20140610-1547 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.7@13362) for context '/ProjectManagerWeb']]

  [2015-10-25T01:21:16.323+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1445725276323] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Running on PrimeFaces 5.0]]

  [2015-10-25T01:21:16.390+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00172] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1445725276390] [levelValue: 800] [[
   Loading application [ProjectManagerWeb] at [/ProjectManagerWeb]]]

 [2015-10-25T01:21:16.532+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1445725276532] [levelValue: 800] [[
  ProjectManagerWeb was successfully deployed in 6 841 milliseconds.]]
```

**PS:** The whole project is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-LAX_pu8QCUSFJMN2FQTnVFMzA/view?usp=sharing). Note you must manually install the artifact `ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar`, the necessary jar (`ojdbc6`) is in the project folder!

Comment: The warning is just a warning. You can perform tricks to get rid of it, but that wouldn't help with your actual problem (which means that this question is badly titled too).

Comment: @Kayaman If you want I'm ok with you edditing it :)

Comment: Do you have a log file?  Is the name of the persistence unit correct in your code? Is the database connection correct or should you rather use a JNDI lookup?

Comment: @miw The persistence unit and connection I believe to be correct.

Comment: Then it comes back to my first question: what does the log file say?  That would turn 'belief' into 'facts'...

Comment: There is no such option "create-or-extend-tables" for that property. Should be "create" or "drop-and-create".

Comment: Tryed with both `create` and `drop-and-create`, neither of them creates any tables.

Comment: so look in the JPA providers log for when the persistence unit is opened and the EMF created. At that point it should do some schema stuff. If it doesn't then raise a bug on it. The JPA provider I use (DataNucleus) simply kicks in at that point and my schema is created

Comment: @NeilStockton I added these line to the persistence.xml - 
`<property name="eclipselink.logging.file"        value="JPA.log" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level"       value="ALL" />        
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.logger"      value="DefaultLogger"/>`
, but it doesn't seem to make any file.

Comment: Have you tried setting up DataSource in glassfish, and referencing it as `<jta-data-source>` instead of hardcoding it into persistence.xml?

Comment: @Deltharis Actually that's what I did today and it worked. You can post it as an answer so I can accept it.